# Pass value to model by create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass additional value to my model when I use the create action:

For now I have a list of products with 2 buttons(size M and size L) to add to cart:

index.html.erb

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
<tr>
<td><%= product.name %></td>
<td><%= product.size.medium %> | <%= button_to 'Medium, line_items_path(product_id: product.id) %></td>
<td><%= product.size.large %> | <%= button_to 'Large, line_items_path(product_id: product.id) %></td>
</tr>
```

line_items_controller.rb

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

 def create
  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  size = product.details.first.size
  @line_item = @cart.add_item(product_id, size.medium)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back,
        notice: 'Product was successfully created.'}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new"}
    end
 end
end
end
```

cart.rb

```
def add_item(product_id, size)
    current_item = picks.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item
    else
      current_item = items.build(product_id: product_id, size: size)
    end
    current_item
 end
```

From my code here, every item I created have the value of size: size.medium. How can I rewrite my code so that the value of size depends on the button I click. So if I click button "Large", my line_item will save the value of product_id and size.large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an ***extra parameter*** to the `button_to` and access it in the controller through `params` like below.

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
<tr>
<td><%= product.name %></td>
<td><%= product.size.medium %> | <%= button_to 'Medium', line_items_path(product_id: product.id, size: 'Medium') %></td>
<td><%= product.size.large %> | <%= button_to 'Large', line_items_path(product_id: product.id, size: 'Large') %></td>
</tr>
```

And in the controller access it like `params[:size]`

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    size = params[:size]
    @line_item = @cart.add_item(product_id, size)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Product was successfully created.'}
      else
        format.html { render action: "new"}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To give some context to `Pavan`'s answer, you have to make a distinction between passing parameters through the *routes* and through the *form* (`button_to` creates a small form):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :line_items #-> url.com/line_items
```

--

The `button_to` code `@pavan` suggested was to pass the `size` through the route.

Although this will work well, the right way is to [add the params to the `button_to` form itself](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

```
<%= button_to 'Medium', line_items_path, params: { product_id: product.id, size: 'Medium' } %>
```

This creates hidden fields in the form which will appear like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="x">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="y">
```

---

You'll also want to use a loop where possible (to prevent code repetition):

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
   <%= content_tag :tr do %>
     <%= content_tag :td, product.name %>
     <% product.size.each do |size| %>
        <%= content_tag :td do %>
           <%= size %> | <%= button_to size.titleize, line_items_path, params: { product_id: product.id, size: size } %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```